# Check Box Label Above Checkbox. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, checkbox

I am using C# visual studio 2010 to develop an ASP.NET website.

I dynamically create a checkbox at run time.

```
CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox();
chkbox.ID = "chk" + checkboxID;

// Add our checkbox to the panel
dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(chkbox);
chkbox.Text = checkboxName;
```

By default, the label is displayed to the right of the checkbox.  I can successfully move the label from side to side by adjusting chkbox.TextAlign = TextAlign.Right / Left.

What I can not figure out for the life of me is how to set the Text above the check box.

I am not looking for any kind of hack like, verticle-align:-3px as this will not work for me because I let the user pick the font and size of the text.  It will not always be -3px in depth.

Comment: and what's wrong with using CSS to accomplish this?

Comment: @ErOx And how would you accomplish this with css?  I am not using a label and a checkbox.  I am using a label with the text property defined.

Comment: Then use a label. This is what setting the TextAlign.Left|Right property does anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the text align property to **TextAlign.Left** then use CSS to set the label's display to: **block**.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you should go with a new Control where you add a separate Label below the Checkbox (actually wrapping the checkbox).
Derieve that class from CheckBox, and override (or define new if not virtual) the Text property, so it will now set the upper Label's text.
This will actually be a good example of Decorator pattern.

Comment: Dynamically adding a location for a label / checkbox as well as keeping them tied together ( I dynamically create about 20 of these) seems like it would be quite the head ache, am I wrong?

Comment: You're not going to dynamically set the location in that case (although you can). You have that location already preset in the wrapping control. The only thing left for you to do is to instanciate the control and set the Label property.